# Centering div so content of it will always be in middel

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center the div{class="informationbox"} so that the div's inside will always be centered in the page, No matter how many divs there is inside.

```css
.informationbox{
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="informationbox">
        <div style="display: inline-block;">
            <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/342/19541848580_7f925817c9_b.jpg" />
            <p>Something</p>
            <p>Wall of Text</p>
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block;">
            <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/342/19541848580_7f925817c9_b.jpg" />
            <p>Something</p>
            <p>Wall of Text</p>
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block;">
            <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/342/19541848580_7f925817c9_b.jpg" />
            <p>Something</p>
            <p>Wall of Text</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want the divs inside or the informaiton div to be in the center?

Comment: The div inside the information div, has to be centered in the page. so no matter if there is 1 or 10 then they will be as centered as posible

Comment: what about the information div? You want it to be center of the parent element?

Comment: There is simple flexbox solution http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WodaPZ

Answer (score 3):

Just add text-align center to the informationbox and remove all other css. Note that this ONLY works because (all) your content is inline (your divs have `display: inline-block`).

```css
.informationbox{
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="informationbox">
        <div style="display: inline-block;">
            <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/342/19541848580_7f925817c9_b.jpg" />
            <p>Something</p>
            <p>Wall of Text</p>
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block;">
            <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/342/19541848580_7f925817c9_b.jpg" />
            <p>Something</p>
            <p>Wall of Text</p>
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block;">
            <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/342/19541848580_7f925817c9_b.jpg" />
            <p>Something</p>
            <p>Wall of Text</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

**WARNING**: When you use this solution, you might end up with unwanted space between the inline-block elements. This is due to the fact that there is a 'space' (the character) between them. This can be solved by opening the next div IMMEDIATELY after closing the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.informationbox{
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around; /*or "center"*/
}
```

```html
<div class="informationbox">
        <div style="display: inline-block;">
            <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/342/19541848580_7f925817c9_b.jpg" />
            <p>Something</p>
            <p>Wall of Text</p>
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block;">
            <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/342/19541848580_7f925817c9_b.jpg" />
            <p>Something</p>
            <p>Wall of Text</p>
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block;">
            <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/1/342/19541848580_7f925817c9_b.jpg" />
            <p>Something</p>
            <p>Wall of Text</p>
        </div>
</div>
```